# MO scheme for coordination complexes (tetrahedral) - Heteroligand vs. homoligand

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, coordination-compounds

How is the MO diagram drawn for a tetrahedral complex with heteroligands (e.g. $\ce{[NiCl2(PPh3)2]}$) different from a tetrahedral complex with the same type of ligand? Do we consider the same "a1 and t2" SALCs as in the case of same ligand type tetrahedral?

Answer (score 1):

Bis(triphenylphosphine)nickel chloride can have be tetrahedral or square planar depending on conditions. In any case the SALCs for a tetrahedral complex with heteroligands will depend on the point group of the complex. For [NiCl2(PPh3)2], the point gorup is C2v and not Td like for same ligand tetrahedral. You need to check the character tables

Comment: Why does [NiCl2(PPh3)2] have a C2v point group? Wouldn't it be more logical if it have Td point group? If so, did you not include the two Cl ligand in determining the point group because I think the only way the complex would be a C2v is that when its geometry is similar to water.